# Passing parameters - Python to HTML with Javascript

Tags: java, python, html, parameter-passing

I have a simple Python file which uses the QtWebkit.QWebView to display a google maps page.

This is done by calling the HTML which includes some java script.

What I don't know how to do is get the co-ordinates from Python to the java script in the HTML file.

Perhaps someone can point me in the right direction?

PYTHON:

```
class MainWin(QDialog,MainFrm.Ui_MainWin):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWin,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


        self.lat = -25.723146
        self.long = 28.267628
        self.GMapWidget.load("markers.html?",coords = self.lat)



app = QApplication(sys.argv)
frm=MainWin()
frm.show()
app.exec_()
```

***HTML:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body, #map-canvas { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCrRTR8nZX3m6g_nYbilamyKSBHx9QUdfw">
    </script>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body, #map-canvas { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCrRTR8nZX3m6g_nYbilamyKSBHx9QUdfw">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      lt = -25.723146
      ln = 28.267628
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: { lat: lt, lng:  ln},
          zoom: 8
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
            mapOptions);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need a real-time event communication system between your Python app and your JavaScript app, you can establish an [SSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) or WebSocket connection between both. I am not sure if you want this additional complexity, though.

In case a static (one-time) parameter exchange is sufficient, you can work with templates. Make a template from your HTML file with placeholders for `lt` and `ln` values. [`string.Template`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Template) in the stdlib is useful here.

The template file (call it e.g. `"markers.html.tpl"`) content might then look like so:

```
[...]
<script type="text/javascript">
  lt = $latitude
  ln = $longitude 
[...]
```

Instead of simply loading the HTML file:

```
self.GMapWidget.load("markers.html?",coords = self.lat)
```

you first read the template, insert the values, write the new HTML file, and only then load the widget:

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from string import Template


with open("markers.html.tpl", "rb") as f:
    tpl = Template(f.read().decode("utf-8"))

htmlcontent = tpl.substitute(latitude=1.2, longitude=2.5)

with NamedTemporaryFile() as f:
    f.write(htmlcontent.encode("utf-8")
    self.GMapWidget.load(f.name)
```

This is a naive, but reliable approach. Note that you ca re-use the template, so `tpl = Template(f.read().decode("utf-8"))` is required only once, but can be followed by as many `tpl.substitute()` calls as you wish.

Apart from this, I am not aware of any particular interface between Python code and the WebKit component, for you do dynamically fiddle with the state of JavaScript variables.

Comment: Thank you very much for this input. It has helped me tremendously. I just had a problem with the loading of the file. It caused the following error QNetworkAccessFileBackendFactory: URL has no schema set, use file:// for files.

Comment: but got around that by using the setHtml - Thanks again

Comment: Happy to have helped! This is indeed one of those problems where you need some technological overview to come up with solutions. I am very sure that others might have come up with different approaches, but the concepts I proposed are quite solid. Remember: you can accept answers with the green checkmark -- this helps me, and others, too!